# apps script detect new row insertion in external spreadsheet & get the values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

How can I detect new row insertion in spreadsheet2 through google apps script in a spreadsheet1. I want get the values of the row whenever new row is inserted in that spreadsheet2. The place where I want to get values is spreadsheet1's script.

I'm using this in my spreadsheet1 script

```
var ssId2 = "1Ii0w0RPcaQWKYUDhY**************************";
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId2);
```

Here, I cannot determine what will be the range of the new row inserted??

```
var values = range.getValues();
var row = values[0];
var uname = row[1];
```

And how can I get the values of the new row inserted whenever only change occurs i.e **only when the new row gets inserted**.

I've tried searching all over the internet and spent a few days but can't get it done.

Comment: You can't read event statuses of spreadsheet B from a script in spreadsheet A, because B only provides triggers to a script installed in B. You will have to modify A and B, such that B detects the new data with its trigger, and then sends that data to spreadsheet A (either directly or to a webapp written in the script for A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not recommend you to use onEdit trigger in this case, especially if you have multiple users who can make changes concurrently, because of this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760530).

> "you'll have to assume that onEdit triggers are best-effort, but may
>   not catch all edits done to the spreadsheet."

You can update sheets of spreadsheet2 with additional column and run script, which checks every 5/10 min. whether the row is empty. In case if it's not empty, assign some value to the column (Y/N) and next get values of non-empty row and set it to the spreadhsheet1,based on the status of the column.